# windows client connect to windows server through VPN problems

Tags: windows, git, svn

I have vpn connection to windows server from windows 7 professional client. When I connect to the server in remote connection or svn checkout, it always disconnect after several seconds. e.g. in below screen , it happens in SVN checkout. In the client office vpn connect to main office windows server, it mostly happened in my computer. I have helped other colleagues to setup svn and checkout projects, they are successful... I really do not know why. Moreover when I remote connect to this windows server, after several seconds I will be disconnected. I cannot start working due to this problem. Please help.

[image]

Comment: In svn checkout, when the project is small, it will be successful in my computer but not when the project is large. Is it due to transfer size??

Comment: I have turn off windows firewall but still same problem

Comment: Is it related to McAfee or anti-virus program??

Comment: Yes, antivirus might be the root cause. I would suggest you try up-to-date `svn.exe` client to see whether you'll get the same error.